# ってば and もう: not sure how to use these in a sentence

Tags: meaning, interjections

I'm not sure how to use ってば and もう in a sentence.

> やだってばもう！

^from 明日、ママがいない first episode at the beginning (if you watched it)

How can I use ってば and もう in a sentence?

Comment: Are you sure it's not `いやだってばもう` ?

Comment: I'm sure it's not that.

Comment: @Ninj0r 「いや」 is often pronounced as 「や」.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

「やだ」(*yada*) is a casual way of saying "I don't like it" or "I don't want to" or even "Gross" or something along those lines -- mainly, "dislike." You often hear little kids use this word as a stand-alone sentence.

「◯◯ってば」(*-tte ba*) connects to what came directly before it and means "I already said ___!" or "I already told you ____!" or "I'm telling you, ____!"

「もう」(*mou*) can mean "already" as in 「もう帰った」(*Mou kaetta* = "_____ already went home."), however 「もう！」 is a stand-alone word that means something more along the lines of "Sheesh!" or "Jeez!" or "Man!" (It is not a swear word or euphemism for one, but depending on the user's style of English, some English speakers might more likely say a stronger word like "God!" or "Shit!" in this kind of situation, such as "You're being such a brat. *God.*"). If the tone of the sentence is not agitated, it could be a softer「もう」like in the title of the manga [『まったく君ってばもう』](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8F%E5%90%9B%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%B0%E3%82%82%E3%81%86-%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A3%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9F%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9-%E9%9B%B2%E4%B9%8B%E5%8A%A9/dp/4199606254) (*Mattaku Kimi-tte ba, Mou* = *[You're Always] Totally You, Sheesh...*) where the 「もう」is slightly miffed but affectionate like the English phrase, "You crazy kid, you."

So the sentence could be written as 「『やだ』ってば！もう！」or「『やだ』ってば、もう！」.

**To answer your question, "How can I use ってば and もう in a sentence?"**, 「もう！」 is usually uttered as its own sentence, but when said quickly right on the heels of the previous sentence, it could be combined with a 「、」 to make it into one sentence. However, realize that 「ってば」 is associated with the preceding words, not with the 「もう！」.  You could make a sentence such as 「『行かない』ってば、もう！」(*Ikanai-tte ba, mou!* = "I said I'm not going, dang it!") or 「『邪魔なんだ』ってば、もう！」(*Jama nan da-tte ba, mou!* = "'You're bothering me,' I said! Jeez!" or "I said, 'You're in the way!' Jeez!")

Answer (score 4):

> やだってばもう！ ≒
>
> 「やだ!」ってば、もう！

In this context, 「ってば」 is a sentence-ending particle that expresses one's frustration over the listener's inability to understand one's feelings.

「～～**と**[言]{い}えば」 ⇒ 「～～**って**言えば」 ⇒ 「～～ってば」

Thus, one could see that 「って」 functions quotatively.  "I'm saying ~~~~~.  Can't you understand?"

Moving on to 「もう」...

「もう」 has several meanings. The most well-known among J-learners would be "already".  (Just my observation.  I am not a J-learner.)

In this context, however, while officially an adverb, 「もう」 functions just like an interjection that helps express your feelings emphatically.  Basically, it is saying ***"I've had enough (of this)!"***

So, 「やだってばもう！」 means something along the lines of:

> "I'm saying I don't want to (or 'I can't'), can't you hear?"